# There have `6/` `6.0/`, `6.1/` ... `6.9/` directories in the yum repos, what's the difference between `6.x` with `6/`

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I fond a yum [repo](http://repos.lax.quadranet.com/centos/)

I have some questions about it:

1. There have list of directories, I find only the latest version directory have content: 
   [image]

the old `4.2` do not have content, why?
[image]

2. the version `6` have  `6/` `6.0/`, `6.1/` ... `6.9/`, what's the difference between `6.x` with `6/`?
3. In the [buildlogs.centos.org](https://buildlogs.centos.org/) site, there have `c6-*/`directories and `c7-*/`directories, if I download them, where should I put ?

---

**EDIT-01**

I still have a question, that is a saying the `6/` point to `6.<latest>`, the content below the `6/` directory is as the same as `6.2/`.
when the repo at first the latest version is `6.2/` the `6/` point to `6.2/`, when the version become `6.8/` will the directory `6/` delete all the data and re-copy the `6.8/`'s data? so the `6/` point to the latest content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the repository is arranged so that e.g. the `6/` directory points into `6.<latest>`, as long as that major release is supported. For example, when 6.10 was the latest 6.x version, `6/` would be the same as `6.10/`. When 6.11 was released, `6/` changed to point into `6.11/` instead.

The `6/` is probably actually just a symbolic link that points to whichever `6.x/` directory is the latest one, although the web listing won't tell you that.

When a particular major release has reached End-Of-Life (currently all 5.x and older), the content is replaced with a simple `readme` file indicating that if you need packages for obsolete releases you should find them in `http://vault.centos.org/<version.number>` instead.

The main `vault.centos.org` system also does not allow downloading any `*.iso` files to save bandwidth, although you can see they are there. If you need `*.iso` files for old releases, you should use one of the CentOS vault mirror servers listed on the vault page, preferably one that's physically nearest to you.

The [buildlogs.centos.org](https://buildlogs.centos.org/) site, as the name implies, contains an archive of CentOS binary packages, the corresponding source code packages, and package build logs. These are not required for mirroring a basic RPM package repositories. The names of `c6-*/` and `c7-*/`sub-directories reflect the various optional sub-repositories.

Unless you are troubleshooting a particular bug or working for CentOS Quality Assurance, they are not particularly interesting: if you don't know why you would need them, you probably should not download them. If you *do* need them, then you should put them where you need them.

If you are maintaining a CentOS repository mirror, you should read the [CentOS mirroring guidelines](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreatePublicMirrors) to understand the best way to do it. It also mentions the address of a CentOS-mirror mailing list, and the Freenode IRC channel #centos-mirror: you could ask there to reach people that are likely to have the best knowledge about CentOS mirrors.

Comment: But, how about the such `c6-extras/` directories, what's them?

Comment: @244boy Edited my answer.

Comment: i download a public repo, the `6/` is not a symbolic link .

Comment: and if I want the content of `buildlogs.centos.org` to be my public repo's part, and users can install `buildlogs`'s packages from my repo. how to do with it?

Comment: Is your download method capable of replicating symbolic links? `rsync` might do it, `wget` will not. And `buildlogs.centos.org` is not a yum repository. If something is in the buildlogs server but not in the actual CentOS repositories, that probably means the package failed to build correctly or is very experimental: the buildlogs server is a service for people that build new packages to CentOS. It allows developers to troubleshoot the autobuild process.